# Link em uma NSAttributedString

Tags: swift

Tenho uma string que na verdade é um trecho em HTML. Uso o seguinte método pra converter esse trecho em uma string e setar na label

```
let s = Descricao.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode)! 

    let attrStr = try? NSAttributedString( 

        data: s, 

        options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], 

        documentAttributes: nil) 



    lbl_Titulo.title = Nome_Convenio 

    lbl_Convenio.numberOfLines = 0 

    lbl_Convenio.sizeToFit() 

    lbl_Convenio.textAlignment = .left 

    lbl_Convenio.attributedText = attrStr
```

Acontece que esse html pode ter links, que não estão abrindo o browser quando clicados. Como fazer para esses links serem clicáveis?

Comment: para isso utilizo um UILabel que permite links: https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 0):

Seria uma opção usar um Text View? fará o mesmo efeito, e nele é possível marcar os `Data Detectors` no textview na sua storyboard para a identificação de links, datas, telefones, etc...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]